# Accidentally overwrote mysql database with empty data

Tags: mysql, disaster-recovery

I accidently imported an empty database backup file into the same database, using mysql-workbench. Is there any way to undo this and get the data back? The backup available is 4 months old which is too old to restore, any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

No, you can't. You have overwritten the database so your best course of action is to restore from the latest backup. If that is 4 months old, that's it, you lost 4 months of data.

You should take backups more often and also before any critical operation (like this one) that has the chance of destroying data if it goes wrong.

---

**Addendum**:

Before you go and overwrite again the database by restoring the 4-months old backup - and depending on the value of the data you lost - you can take this action:

- stop the database instance/service, immediately.
- make sure it doesn't restart (MySQL is often installed with a "watch-dog" that restarts it when it fails).
- take a complete OS-level backup of the mysql directory or the whole file system, to another, external disk / file-system.

You may be able to find (very expensive) companies/services that may be able to recover some of the data you lost.

It might even be better - if you go the expensive route - to keep this machine (completely shut down or stop all services but not shut down or do whatever these consultants tell you to follow; contact them before you take any severe action) and restore the backup in a separate machine, so you have the best chances of recovering whatever data you can from the existing machine/installation.